# How can I duplicate Magento top.links into header and footer

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento themeing and am trying to do some basic theme changes.

I would like to display the same top.links menu in my header and my footer.

I added the block to the footer in page.xml:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

and added this code to the footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

After doing this the menu shows up in the footer, but no longer in the header. I am guessing a block can only be displayed once? How can I show it on both the header and the footer?

Thank you.

Comment: You can call this without xml. Just call this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?> in footer page.

Comment: @K-THIHA - I attempted this but it didn't work. Just comes up with nothing inside the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

in your layout page.xml file:

```
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer.links" as="footerLinks">
                //you need to add the links you wanna show here, for example:
                <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
                //search for 'addLink' in the layout xml files to find all the links you want
            </block>
            ...//rest of footer's content
        </block>
```

and in your footer.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footerLinks') ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you dont need to copy the block in xml , if you just copy the code in footer file it will work